# Splunk Java SDK - query time range

Tags: java, splunk

I'm using Java SDK to query Splunk. I'm getting the proper results when I don't give a time range to the search query. But when I specify a time range I find that the results that are returned don't match the time that I gave. It always returns the newest results, irrespective of the date range that I specified.

```
Args outputArgs = new Args();
outputArgs.put("output_mode", outputMode);
outputArgs.put("earliest_time", "2013-07-29T12:00:00.000");
outputArgs.put("latest_time",   "2013-07-30T12:00:00.000");
```

Can you please let me know if the time format that I have specified is not proper? Or do I need to have some additional code to specify time range?

Comment: Can you give us the result time?